# Is there an easy way to achieve a multirow bookmark toolbar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

How can I get a multi-row bookmark toolbar in Firefox without writing code? All I can find are outdated extensions and CSS tricks.

Comment: The best way to do this is using css changes. https://www.e2app.com/memories/how-to-get-multirow-bookmarks-back-in-firefox-57-and-newer/ Is the simplest guide I could find